# Java - I struggle making 2 methods based on a UML Diagram

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm a beginner, I have a Java exercise which is based on a Astah UML Diagram. I struggle doing 2 methods:

1. Class: MyDate - Method : `+now() : MyDate`  - I suppose I have to return the time in real-time.
2. Class: Apartment - Method : `+rentTo(tenant : Tenant, rentedFrom : MyDate) : void` - I have coded the part with `(tenant : Tenant)` but I don't know what to do with `(rentedFrom : MyDate)`.

This is the code for the Apartment class, rentTo method:

```
public void rentTo(Tenant tenant, MyDate rentedFrom)
  {
    this.tenant = tenant;
    //rentedFrom = ?
  }
```

This is the diagram: [image: UML Diagram]

Any help/ clue will help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would appear from the diagram that the tenant has a 'rented from' date, so presumably you are to set that date by calling the setter on the tenant.

Comment: So it will look like this?: 
`public void rentTo(Tenant tenant, MyDate rentedFrom)
  {
    this.tenant = tenant;
    tenant.setRentedFrom(rentedFrom);
  }`

Comment: I think so, yes.